# For every column and cell in dataframe fill in NaNs/Nulls with random value from that column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill in NaN/null values for every column and every cell within a column in dataframe by random sampling from that column (e.g sample non-NaN value). I am doing right now the following

```
   for col in df:
        count = 0
        while True:
            sample = df[col].sample(n=1)
            count += 1
            if pd.notna(sample.item()):
                df[col].replace(sample, np.nan, inplace=True)
                break
            if count >= 100:
                break
```

Which is incorrect because:

1. it has this hack to try to sample 100 times with a hope that you finally find non-NaN within 100 tries.
2. It would fill cells with the sample sample, while **I would like to sample randomly a value for every cell separately e.g not to have any skew**
3. Well it does not work for some reason in any case, resulting df has NaNs as before.

Note: dataframe contains both numbers and strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `np.random.choice` to generate a sample from a population of values:

```
sample = np.random.choice(pop, size=len(df)-len(pop), replace=True)
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)).astype(float)
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=arr.shape, dtype=bool)
arr[mask] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(df)
#      0    1    2
# 0  8.0  NaN  0.0
# 1  1.0  3.0  2.0
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 3  6.0  NaN  7.0
# 4  NaN  8.0  5.0
# 5  1.0  4.0  6.0
# 6  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 7  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 8  8.0  NaN  NaN
# 9  5.0  NaN  2.0

for col in df:
    mask = pd.isnull(df[col])
    pop = df[col].dropna()
    if len(pop):
        sample = np.random.choice(pop, size=len(df)-len(pop), replace=True)
        df.loc[mask, col] = sample


print(df)
```

yields a result such as

```
     0    1    2
0  8.0  4.0  0.0
1  1.0  3.0  2.0
2  1.0  8.0  2.0
3  6.0  3.0  7.0
4  8.0  8.0  5.0
5  1.0  4.0  6.0
6  1.0  8.0  2.0
7  8.0  4.0  6.0
8  8.0  4.0  7.0
9  5.0  3.0  2.0
```

---

`df[col]` returns a Series. Modifying this Series is not guaranteed to
modify `df` itself. Thus

```
df[col].replace(sample, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

modifies the Series returned by `df[col]` but fails to modify `df`.

Generally, to ensure that you modify a DataFrame, use `df.loc[...] = ...`
or `df.iloc[...] = ...` or generate a new DataFrame and reassign it to `df` (e.g. `df = new_df`), or generate a new column of values and reassign it to a column (e.g. `df[col] = values`).

Comment: When running I get "ValueError: a must be non-empty" at this line "sample = np.random.choice(pop, size=len(df) - len(pop), replace=True)"

Comment: My df has mixed type data. does it work for mixed type data? It seems like it should, but just making a note

Comment: `ValueError: a must be non-empty` would occur if `len(pop)` is 0. In other words, that column has no non-nan values. What would you like to happen in this case? Keeping all nan values or raising a ValueError are both reasonable possibilities...

Comment: Mixed dtype is not a problem since each column has a single shared dtype, and we are assigning values which have the same dtype.

Comment: I changed the code to simply keep NaNs if the column has no non-NaN values.

Comment: After reading your post more closely, it was apparent that mine was pretty much a copy (-:

Comment: I thought it showed a nice alternative. It uses more Pandas methods instead of NumPy functions.